# jQuery 3.6.0 and jsPlumb Community Edition 5.10.4 RC: Uncaught TypeError: el.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I can't make the current versions of jQuery (3.6.0) and jsPlumb Community Edition (5.10.4 RC) work with each other. I use the current version of Mozilla Firefox on Windows 10.

If I initialize my jsPlumb structures inside a

```
$(document).ready( function(){ ... } );
```

function, nothing happens but the browser console shows a warning

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: el.getAttribute is not a function getAttribute@file:///path/js/jsplumb.bundle.js:14643:19
manage@file:///path/js/jsplumb.bundle.js:7210:18
...
```

and an exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: el.getAttribute is not a function
getAttribute file:///path/js/jsplumb.bundle.js:14643
manage file:///path/js/jsplumb.bundle.js:7210
manage file:///path/js/jsplumb.bundle.js:15589
_internal_newEndpoint file:///path/js/jsplumb.bundle.js:7368
addEndpoint file:///path/js/jsplumb.bundle.js:7551
<anonymous> file:///path/js/structuregraph.js:20
...
```

Here's the code of line 14643 and around of jsplumb.bundle.js:

```
...
}, {
  key: "setAttribute",
  value: function setAttribute(el, name, value) {
    el.setAttribute(name, value);
  }
}, {
  key: "getAttribute",
  value: function getAttribute(el, name) {
    return el.getAttribute(name);   // <----------------------- line 14643 
  }
}, {
  key: "setAttributes",
  value: function setAttributes(el, atts) {
    for (var i in atts) {
      el.setAttribute(i, atts[i]);
    }
  }
}, {
...
```

What is the problem with this `getAttribute` function?

Answer (score 0):

What does the code at `file:///path/js/structuregraph.js:20` look like?